# Check Lock Keys state from command-line

Tags: command-line, capslock, numlock

I want to check Lock keys (i.e Caps Lock, Num Lock, Scroll Lock etc.) state (On/Off) from command-line. How do I check state via terminal command?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

simply run:

```
xset q
```

From `man xset`:

```
q       The q option gives you information on the current settings.
```

In the top section of the output, you will find your information, looking like:

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000003
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   on     01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
```

---

You can use `grep` to get specific result as follows:

```
$ xset -q | grep Caps
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
```

Comment: I want to use caps state as an if conditional. (Specifically, I want to bind caps to control, but I only want to do that when caps isn't press, that leaves me IN PERMANENT ALL CAPS, WHICH IS NOT WHAT I WANTED! (phew).

Suggestions?

Comment: What could be a possible reason if this didn't work? For me, it's always "Caps Lock: off".

Answer (score 3):

With `xset` you could use the following `sed` command:

```bsh
xset -q | sed -n 's/^.*Caps Lock:\s*\(\S*\).*$/\1/p'
```

As an example, say you want to check if caps lock is enabled, and if so to disable it. For that you could do:

```bsh
caps_lock_status=$(xset -q | sed -n 's/^.*Caps Lock:\s*\(\S*\).*$/\1/p')
if [ $caps_lock_status == "on" ]; then
  echo "Caps lock on, turning off"
  xdotool key Caps_Lock
else
  echo "Caps lock already off"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not in X ("graphical mode"), but in a terminal:

```
$ /usr/bin/setleds
Current default flags:  NumLock off   CapsLock off   ScrollLock off
Current flags:          NumLock off   CapsLock off   ScrollLock off
Current leds:           NumLock off   CapsLock off   ScrollLock off
```

Similarly, if you want to know the state of a terminal, but you're not in it (e.g. you came in through SSH):

```
setleds < /dev/tty1
```

You might need to be root, due to /dev/tty* permissions.

See the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setleds) for more (the command can even set the leds, reading them is just a side effect).